# Add third party SSL(comodo positive wildcard) certificate on managed wordpress hosting by godaddy

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have bought SSL certificate for my domain and all subdomian(*.abc.in). My main domain(abc.in) and sub-domain(blog.abc.in) are running on different server. I have installed certificate on my main server, where abc.in is hosted. and I am able to access https://abc.in now.

My blogs are on sub-domain blog.abc.in, and I want to make this also accessible from https://blog.abc.in(sub-domain). This sub-domain is linked with managed wordpress hosting provided by godaddy. I can't do it since i dont have access of its server. can someone tell me how to proceed fro the same.
NOTE:  I have my .crt, .key and .cer file with me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: thankyou bro, shifting it on web apps stack exchnage.

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. For whatever reasons, Stack Overflow does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851).